# Alternative interpretation to the word 'rest'?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, learning

Let's assume I've created the headline:

> Rafael Nadal pulls out of U.S. Open and will miss rest of 2021.

When writing the text about this, can I make the word *rest* to mean repose? Like Nadal misses his repose time of 2021 as a punishment for pull out U.S Open?

Comment: What is "repose time" in this context? How is this "punishment"?

Comment: Killing Time, in my fictional example every player has available time he/she can use for resting, provided by his/her sponsor. Just to make a context. In this case would that be possible my thought?

Comment: It's a headline, so it drops words at the cost of introducing ambiguity. It could mean missing rest as in relaxation, or more probably rest as in remainder. You could take the less obvious interpretation, but as a journalist your goal is to inform your readers. So can you? Yes. Should you? No.

Comment: If I wanted the “repose” meaning I’d say “miss ***his*** rest of 2021.

Comment: @KannE Maybe he has to be a ballboy instead of just slacking off at home. :)

Comment: "Rafael Nadal pulls out of U.S. Open and will miss his 2021 rest."

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The word "rest" there clearly means "remainder", not anything like "repose".